# wireguard - how to link a remote server with two connections

Tags: wireguard

I have 3 sites. Site A and B are not related. Both need a wireguard connection to a server on site C. How do I accomplish this?

```
┌──────────────┐              ┌─────────────────────┐             ┌──────────────┐
│              │              │                     │             │              │
│    SITE A    │              │       SITE C        │             │    SITE B    │
│              │   WG0        │    ┌───────────┐    │    WG1      │              │
│              │   10.0.0.0   │    │  SERVER   │    │  11.0.0.0   │              │
│        ──────┼──────────────┼───►│           ├────┼─────────────┼──►           │
│              │              │    │           │    │             │              │
│        ◄─────┼──────────────┼────┤           │◄───┼─────────────┼────          │
│              │  port        │    │           │    │  port       │              │
│              │  50001       │    ├───────────┤    │  50002      │              │
└──────────────┘              └────┴───────────┴────┘             └──────────────┘
```

The first connection WG0 works well with   `PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp3s0 -j MASQUERADE   PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp3s0 -j MASQUERADE`

If I do the same with WG1 I get no connection. The tunels use different ports. How do I set up this topology correctly?

Comment: I don't think your `MASQUERADE` rule makes any sense. Presumably instead of `-o enp3s0` you want `-o %i`, which would give you a different rule for each interface rather than the same rule for both, which is what you currently have.

Comment: If I leave out MASQUERADE I can ping the server in site C and ssh to it but a web service running on it doesn't answer. to wg1.

Comment: To be clear I'm not suggesting that you *remove* the masquerade rule; I'm suggesting that you change it to be interface specific. Additional, if  your system needs a rule to masquerade traffic out `enp3s0` as well, you may want to add that seperately outside of your wireguard postup script.

Comment: Actually, since I only want to access services on the server I guess I don't need NAT.

Comment: IMHO `11.0.0.0` subnet is not allowed. Only `10.x.y.z`. So WG1 must be in `10.11.0.0/16`.